# Making a menu to take me to different scenes

Tags: game-engine, scene

How do I make a mesh clickable so that when I click on it, I go to a different scene? Obviously just making a mouse sensor (left button) > Set Scene (game) isn't working. Whenever I click anywhere on the screen, it goes to the next scene. How do I make it so that when I click a specific object, the actuator goes off?

Answer (score 2):

use both mouse over and mouse left click on the object :

[image]